# Why would JavaScript work correctly in HTML body but not as a JavaScript file in the HTML header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This doesn't work (placed inside the HTML header tag):

```
<script src="files/js/animater/index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

But this works fine (placed inside the HTML body tag):

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $(".active").animate({height: "10%"}, 5000);
    });
</script>
```

Why does the last one work correctly and the first one doesn't?

Comment: Can you post the exact contents of the index.js file, and the HTML file?  One possibility is that you're including the `index.js` file before `jquery.js`.

Comment: When you use the script, have you before added the jquery reference?

Comment: What is the exact error? Is the source path correct?

Comment: Do you know how to see JavaScript errors in your browser?

Comment: How does it not work?  Do you get an error? Nothing happens?

Comment: Yes everything works but when I inspect the element with safari it give a red line by the third line of code

Comment: Has it been placed after the `jQuery` script tags?!

Comment: @user3315843 what is the third line of code?

Comment: @No1_Melman if so, it shouldn't have been

Comment: "$(".active").animate({height: "10%"}, 5000);"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to run your function some how. Like

```
<body onload="animate()">.
```

Otherwise you will need some on document load script in your jquery file. [More Info](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_body_onload.asp)

Comment: This cannot be the answer, unless the information provided in the question was incorrect. Furthermore, using inline event handlers completely beats the purpose of using an unobtrusive JavaScript framework—it's a return to the late 1990s.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Not sure how exactly my answer is **incorrect**. My answer "You need to run your function some how." Was the correct answer. Using the onload in the body tag was a suggested method, a long with using another method of a "document load script" which would not require using the onload in the body tag.

Comment: The OP claims that code is exactly the same and inline vs external is the only difference. If event handler is missing, how could inline code possibly work? (Since this answer works for him, it's obvious that he's lying.)

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario If he put it in the body it would work. [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jcedric/x9sre/4/)

Answer (score 3):

Take out the script tags in the .js file.

Comment: now you're just guessing...

Comment: Now we know that `$(".active")...` is the *third* line. So it was a pretty good guess.

Comment: Betcha he's right though

Comment: He would have found out very easily by asking the question, not posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

In index.js file write this way,

```
(function() {
    $(".active").animate({height: "10%"}, 5000);
}());
```

I hope you'll enjoy :)

Answer (score -1):

You may need an opening slash in your source path: `src="/files/js/animater/index.js"` and you shouldn't need the character set attribute. You ***may*** also need to add `type="text/javascript"` as an attribute.

Comment: The change to the source path would be incorrect. But adding the type attribute would be standards compliant and is a good note to make.